# ARKit World Maps – How To Save/Access Using A Custom UTI File Type?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, arworldmap

I cannot locate any documentation specifically listing the type of file that ARKit saves its World Map as. As far as I know it is a `.arexperience` file. Essentially I am trying to modify a document browser to be able to selectively choose which `.arexperience` file to load.

I have attempted to enable the supported document types, specifically as `public.arexperience` with the LSHandlerRank as type String and Value as Alternate, as well as a CFBundleTypeRole as Type String and Value as Viewer.

I have also set Supports Document Browser to *YES* in info.plist
[Additional document type properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAZeC.png).

9.7.18 EDIT: I am now receiving the following error. Any thoughts on this? I have cleaned the build folder, closed XCode, uninstalled and reinstalled the project, and restarted my computer, but no change. [image: Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code]

9.13.18 EDIT: This error is resulting from a fresh install of both XCode 10 Beta (which includes Swift 4.2) and your sample project. Any idea what's going on? Research indicates a SIGABRT error is the result of an unused outlet, but using the assistant editor which let's me view the connections doesn't display a clear problem...[image]

Comment: You need to use Xcode Beta as this is using Swift 4.2 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seemed like an interesting question, so I thought I would have a go at answering and have a fully working example which can be used a basis for future development by you and others.

It may not be the right approach, but hopefully it will be useful.

Having said this, I'm not entirely sure why you want to use a Document Browser to allow a user to choose `ARWorldMaps`. A simpler approach could be to simply store these in `CoreData`, and allow selection in a `UITableView` for example. Or incorporate the logic below into something similar e.g. when a custom file is opened, save it to `CoreData`, and present all received files that way.

Anyway, here is something which can begin your exploration of this topic in more detail. Although, please note that this is no way optimised, although it should be more than enough to point you in the right direction ^______^.

For your information:

> ARWorldMap conforms to the NSSecureCoding protocol, so you can convert
>   a world map to or from a binary data representation using the
>   NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver classes.

As we want to use a `Custom UTI` to save our `ARWorldMap` we first need to set that up in our `info.plist` file where we set our `UTI` type to `public.data`.

[image]

Which looks like this in the project editor:

[image]

For more information about doing that there is a good tutorial here from [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1018-uiactivityviewcontroller-tutorial-sharing-data).

Having done this, we need to of course save our `ARWorldMap` and allow it to be exported. I have created a `typealias` which is how we will save our data e.g. a key value of `String` and a value of `Data` (our `ARWorldMap`):

```
typealias BMWorlMapItem = [String: Data]

/// Saves An ARWorldMap To The Documents Directory And Allows It To Be Sent As A Custom FileType
@IBAction func saveWorldMap(){

    //1. Attempt To Get The World Map From Our ARSession
    augmentedRealitySession.getCurrentWorldMap { worldMap, error in

        guard let mapToShare = worldMap else { print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)"); return }

        //2. We Have A Valid ARWorldMap So Save It To The Documents Directory
        guard let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: mapToShare, requiringSecureCoding: true) else { fatalError("Can't Encode Map") }

        do {

            //a. Create An Identifier For Our Map
            let mapIdentifier = "BlackMirrorzMap"

            //b. Create An Object To Save The Name And WorldMap
            var contentsToSave = BMWorlMapItem()

            //c. Get The Documents Directory
            let documentDirectory = try self.fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)

            //d. Create The File Name
            let savedFileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("/\(mapIdentifier).bmarwp")

            //e. Set The Data & Save It To The Documents Directory
            contentsToSave[mapIdentifier] = data

            do{
                let archive = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: contentsToSave, requiringSecureCoding: true)
                try archive.write(to: savedFileURL)

                //f. Show An Alert Controller To Share The Item
                let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["Check Out My Custom ARWorldMap", savedFileURL], applicationActivities: [])
                self.present(activityController, animated: true)

                print("Succesfully Saved Custom ARWorldMap")

            }catch{

                print("Error Generating WorldMap Object == \(error)")
            }

        } catch {

            print("Error Saving Custom WorldMap Object == \(error)")
        }

    }
}
```

This also saves the data to the `Documents Directory` on the users device so we can check everything works as expected e.g:

[image]

Once the data is saved, we are then presenting the user with a `UIActivityAlertController` so the user can send the file to their `email` etc.

Since we can now export our data we need to handle how we receive our data when we we select how to open it with our custom handler:

[image]

This is handled in our `AppDelegate` like so:

```
//---------------------------
//MARK: - Custom File Sharing
//---------------------------

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    //1. List Our Custom File Type Which Will Hold Our ARWorldMap
    guard url.pathExtension == "bmarwp" else { return false }

    //2. Post Our Data
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MapReceived"), object: nil, userInfo: ["MapData" : url])

    return true
}
```

As you can see, when our Custom File is received via the `AppDelegate` a `Notification` is sent which we will register for in our ViewController's `viewDidLoad` e.g:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(importWorldMap(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MapReceived"), object: nil)
```

Now we have all this setup we of course need to extract the data so it can be used. Which is achieved like this:

```
/// Imports A WorldMap From A Custom File Type
///
/// - Parameter notification: NSNotification)
@objc public func importWorldMap(_ notification: NSNotification){

    //1. Remove All Our Content From The Hierachy
    self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (existingNode, _) in existingNode.removeFromParentNode() }

    //2. Check That Our UserInfo Is A Valid URL
    if let url = notification.userInfo?["MapData"] as? URL{

        //3. Convert Our URL To Data
        do{
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)

            //4. Unarchive Our Data Which Is Of Type [String: Data] A.K.A BMWorlMapItem
            if let mapItem = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as! BMWorlMapItem,
               let archiveName = mapItem.keys.first,
               let mapData = mapItem[archiveName] {

                //5. Get The Map Data & Log The Anchors To See If It Includes Our BMAnchor Which We Saved Earlier
                if  let unarchivedMap = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [ARWorldMap.classForKeyedUnarchiver()], from: mapData),
                    let worldMap = unarchivedMap as? ARWorldMap {

                    print("Extracted BMWorldMap Item Named = \(archiveName)")

                    worldMap.anchors.forEach { (anchor) in if let name = anchor.name { print ("Anchor Name == \(name)") } }

                    //5. Restart Our Session
                    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
                    configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
                    configuration.initialWorldMap = worldMap
                    self.augmentedRealityView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
                }

            }

        }catch{

            print("Error Extracting Data == \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Now our data is extracted we just need to reconfigure our `Session` and load the map.

You will note that I am logging the `AnchorNames`, as a means of checking whether the process was sucessful, since I create a custom `ARAnchor` named `BMAnchor` which I create using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` like so:

```
//------------------------
//MARK: - User Interaction
//------------------------

/// Allows The User To Create An ARAnchor
///
/// - Parameter gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer
@objc func placeAnchor(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    //1. Get The Current Touch Location
    let currentTouchLocation = gesture.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView)

    //2. Perform An ARSCNHiteTest For Any Feature Points
    guard let hitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchLocation, types: .featurePoint).first else { return }

    //3. Create Our Anchor & Add It To The Scene
    let validAnchor = ARAnchor(name: "BMAnchor", transform: hitTest.worldTransform)
    self.augmentedRealitySession.add(anchor: validAnchor)

}
```

When this is extracted I then generate a model by means on the `ARSCNViewDelegate` which again is useful for checking that our process was successful:

```
//-------------------------
//MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate
//-------------------------

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

        //1. Check We Have Our BMAnchor
        if let name = anchor.name, name == "BMAnchor" {

            //2. Create Our Model Node & Add It To The Hierachy
            let modelNode = SCNNode()

            guard let sceneURL = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/wavingState.dae") else { return nil }

            for childNode in sceneURL.rootNode.childNodes { modelNode.addChildNode(childNode) }

            return modelNode

        }else{

            return SCNNode()
        }

    }

}
```

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction...

And here is a full working example for you and everyone else to experiment with and adapt to your needs: [Sharing ARWorldMaps](https://github.com/BlackMirrorz/ARKitWorldMap)

All you need to do, is wait for the Session to start running, place your model, then press Save. When presented with the Alert email it to yourself, and then check your email, and click on the `.bmarwp` file, which will autoload in the app ^_________^,

In a `Document Based App`, you can then use the Custom file types quite easily.

The following are the requirements for your info.plist:

*(a) Document Types:*

[image]

*(b) Exported Type UTI's:*

[image]

With the info section of your project looking like so:

[image]

As such you will eventually end up with different screens like so:

[image]

Which works in both a basic document based app I created and also in the `Apple Files` app.

Hope it helps...

Comment: BM wanted to say thanks for the detailed response! I'm currently working my way through it now and will continue to update the discussion as I go. I think this is a great starting point from the skim, and I think others will likely find it useful. I think with the release of ARKit 2.0 what I/we are trying to implement will be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

`ARWorldMap` is not a file format, nor is it even a uniform data format. When ARKit creates a world map, it contains all `ARAnchors` present in the session, including custom anchor subclasses defined by whatever app is running ARKit. You can see this in Apple's sample code:

- [Creating a Persistent AR Experience](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_a_persistent_ar_experience) saves an image snapshot in an anchor to help you reorient yourself for resuming a session from the world map later.
- [SwiftShot](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/swiftshot_creating_a_game_for_augmented_reality) saves the game board location in an anchor before sending the world map to another player, so that both players know where the board is before starting a game.

And on top of that, ARKit doesn't even save world map *files* — you're responsible for serializing `ARWorldMap` instances (and whatever they contain) to binary data and saving it to a file. (Or doing something else with that data, like sending it over a network. Or serializing some object graph *containing* an `ARWorldMap` instead of just the map itself. And so on.)

As such, there's no one "ARKit World Map" format — each app that uses ARKit saves its own custom data in a world map, and that data generally isn't meaningful to other apps. (There's SwiftShot maps, ThisApp maps, ThatApp maps, etc.)

---

Now, you *could* define your own file format — just declare that, when your app is `NSKeyedArchiver`-ing an `ARWorldMap` and writing the resulting `Data` to a file, that's a `.myappworldmap` file, which has the UTI `com.example.myapp`, and so on. And you *could* go on to declare that as a user-visible document type and implement Document Browser support. (As described in excellent detail in @BlackMirrorz's answer.)

But *should* you?

In practice, ARKit world maps are (mostly) *transient* data. To be able to relocalize to a previously saved world map, the device loading the map needs to be in very similar real-world environment to the device that saved the map — e.g. in the same room, with the same lighting conditions, with generally the same stuff in the room (yesterday's messy desk isn't always messy in the same way as today's), etc. The older a wold map gets, the more likely the real-world environment it describes is no longer sufficiently similar.

You can use `ARWorldMap` for limited forms of persistence, but it's not really meaningful to treat them as user documents in the sense of, say, a Word/Pages doc or a photo — if you copy them between devices, or to other people elsewhere in the world, there's not much usefulness to them on the receiving end.

For many apps, the only meaningful way to recover sessions from world maps is to save only one map — the last environment the app was used in — and attempt to resume from that map on launch. (Failing that, assume the user is in a different environment and start over.)

If it *is* meaningful for your app to remember multiple past environments — say, an interior-design app that places virtual furniture and might be able to remember different rooms of a home — it's probably more helpful to your user to make the UI for choosing saved maps more integrated with the experience of your app, rather than kicking them out to a generic document browser.

Comment: Fully agree :) CoreData can be useful in situations like you noted at the end of your post :)

Comment: Rick thank you for your response. You've clarified a few things about ARWorldMaps I did not fully understand.

Comment: @BlackMirrorz Any idea how to do ARworldmap in unity?